# C++ QueryPerformanceCounter more accurate than sleep?

Tags: c++, windows

I found an example of QueryPerformanceCounter,

http://advancedcppwithexamples.blogspot.com/2009/08/measuring-elapsed-time-in-c-using_21.html

The example measures a sleep of 100ms with QueryPerformanceCounter which reports only 79ms.

Is there a reason sleep is so inaccurate?

Comment: `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `sleep` do completely different things. Can you clarify?

Comment: How long did you expect sleep to sleep for? How many milliseconds?

Comment: it's not so much inaccurate as the resolution of the various timers differ.  if you look up the associated docs for all the various timing functions you will find that they all have slightly different resolutions and some (such as QPC/QPF) don't work well on certain systems but great on others.

Comment: Also, that test program is broken. It measures not only how long `Sleep` takes, but also how long `cout << "Message"` takes.

Comment: The scheduler works in increments of about 10-100 ms (varies depending on age, server vs. desktop, etc.) Basically, you have to figure a possible inaccuracy of about one increment at each end of a Sleep, so +/- 40 ms is at least a reasonable starting guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sleep` is inaccurate for two reasons: it's based on a very slow clock, and it relies on the OS to resume execution at the end of the period.

The performance counter is actually built into the CPU so it's as accurate as the clock signal that runs the chip. It isn't affected by the OS or tasks whatsoever.